Is there a way to gracefully shut down Apollo Server that's built on top of Deno and Express?
Apollo Server has a plugin called ApolloServerPluginDrainHttpServer that helps shut down the server gracefully when built on top of Node's http.Server. Is there a way to gracefully shut down the server when built on top of Deno or do I just call server.stop() and hope for the best?
